# XML Commenting - ambiguous reference "NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs" in see cref tag?

Tags: resharper, xml-comments, ambiguous

Basically, I have the following: `<see cref="NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs"/>` see tag in my XML Comments. ReSharper states that it is an ambiguous reference and suggests for me to give it as an absolute path, so I use `<see cref="System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs"/>` instead and it still says that it is an ambiguous reference. I have no idea what could possibly be going on that there are 2 classes with the same name in the same namespace??

Anyone know why this is coming up as a problem with ReSharper? I haven't tested this against Sandcastle to see if it complains because this machine doesn't have Sandcastle on it yet, but I do wonder if that'll complain as well.

Comment: This is a good candidate for a bug report to [ReSharper issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues). We've had issues with ambiguous reference inspections in XML doc comments in the past but none of them are unresolved at this point as far as I can see. Are you using ReSharper 5.x?

Comment: OK that should be something newly discovered then. Please feel free to report